# Spring Boot Mongo - E11000 Duplicate Key

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo

I'm building a simple REST api with spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb and I always get a `E11000 duplicate key error` when attempting to insert my 2nd row.

Spring's [getting started guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/) has a pretty simple configuration that I followed, but I must be missing something.

I've dropped the collection, and started fresh, the 1st document saves fine, but the second one tries to save as id=0 as well. **How do I get Spring/Mongo to increment properly?**

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 1 , "n" : 0 , "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: test.game.$_id_ dup key: { : 0 }" , "code" : 11000}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey: { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 1 , "n" : 0 , "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: test.game.$_id_ dup key: { : 0 }" , "code" : 11000}
```

Game

```js
package com.recursivechaos.boredgames.domain;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class Game {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String title;
    private String description;

    public Game() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

Game Repository

```js
package com.recursivechaos.boredgames.repository;

import com.recursivechaos.boredgames.domain.Game;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;

public interface GameRepository extends MongoRepository<Game, Long> {

    List<Game> findByTitle(@Param("title") String title);

}
```

AppConfig

```js
package com.recursivechaos.boredgames.configuration;

import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory;

public class AppConfig {

    public
    @Bean
    MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials("username", "password");
        SimpleMongoDbFactory boredgamesdb = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new Mongo(), "boredgamesdb", userCredentials);
        return boredgamesdb;
    }

    public
    @Bean
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }

}
```

Thanks for looking!

[You can view the whole project here.](https://github.com/AndrewBell/BoredgamesService/tree/mongo-duplicate-key)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'r using a primitive `long` which has an implicit, pre-assigned value. Hence, that value is passed to MongoDB and it persists it as is as it assumes you'd like to define identifiers manually.

The trick is to just use a wrapper type, as this can be `null`, MongoDB detects the absence of the value and will auto-populate an `ObjectID` for you. However, `Long` *is not going to work* as `ObjectID`s do not fit into the number space of a `Long`. The id types supported for auto-generation are `ObjectId`, `String` and `BigInteger`.

All of this is documented in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.conventions.id-field).

Comment: That was the trick! I changed my id field to a String, and the issue was resolved. Thanks!

Comment: I did not even have a id in my pojo and had the same problem. Once I setup my id as BigInteger, this problem was solved. Thanks Oliver!

Answer (score 0):

I also realised if you try to insert the same object more than once it throws a similar error. Apparently it is not because the value of the object is the same but because the object reference is the same for instance

```
// This would throw the exception    
SomeObject object = new SomeObject()
something.insert(object)
something.insert(object)

// But this will not because the references are different although it is 
// the same object
SomeObject object1 = new SomeObject()
SomeObject object2 = new SomeObject()
something.insert(object)
something.insert(object)
```